# The SE chat feed bot seems to be unwell

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, rss

The SE Chat Bot seems to be unwell. This includes Sandbox Feeds and Meta Feeds.

[image: Sandbox Feeds]
[image: Meta Feeds]

Neither of these posts were deleted at the time of posting. Does anyone know what's causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

I would hazard a guess that it is related to the recent name change of the meta domain (from `meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com` to `codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com`, done as part of the [project to make Stack Exchange HTTPS-only](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2017/05/22/https-on-stack-overflow/). Note that links to the old domain still work via redirects, but perhaps this confuses the feed-bots somehow.

Comment: Hm. That would make sense, that sounds like a likely cause for it.

Comment: I've changed the feeds to the new URLs. Let's see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

After @MartinEnder changed the URLs, the oneboxing seems to be working again as observed on TNB. Thanks!

[status-resolved](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-resolved)